# What is the origin and purpose of a new bishop being questioned by a layperson?

Tags: liturgy, anglicanism, bishops

At the enthronement of [Justin Welby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Welby) as [Archbishop of Canterbury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justin_Welby) on 21 March 2013, the following exchange took place as part of the ceremony. Evangeline Kanagasooriam is a  layperson from the diocese, and a pupil at [a school](http://www.kings-school.co.uk) with a [*very*](http://www.kings-school.co.uk/document_1.aspx?id=1:31658&id=1:31637) long association with the cathedral. (The text is from the [order of service](http://www.anglicancommunion.org/_userfiles/File/EnthronementService-v2-PRINT_1.PDF), p14, and it can be enjoyed [on video](http://youtu.be/DLirdU0QIdM?t=2m53s) as well.)

> *When the Archbishop arrives at the West Door he strikes it three times with his pastoral staff. The doors are opened and a fanfare is sounded.*
>
> *Evangeline Kanagasooriam*: We greet you in the name of Christ. Who are you and why do you request entry?
>
> *The Archbishop*: I am Justin, a servant of Jesus Christ, and I come as one seeking the grace of God, to travel with you in his service together.
>
> *Evangeline*: Why have you been sent to us?
>
> *The Archbishop*: I am sent as Archbishop to serve you, to proclaim the love of Christ and with you to worship and love him with heart and soul, mind and strength.
>
> *Evangeline*: How do you come among us and with what confidence?
>
> *The Archbishop*: I come knowing nothing except Jesus Christ and him crucified, and in weakness and fear and in much trembling.
>
> *Evangeline*: Let us then humble ourselves before God and together seek his mercy and strength.

I believe that this is new for the occasion. The [order of service](http://www.anglicancommunion.org/communion/abc/104/enthronementservice.pdf) for Rowan Williams in 2003 does not contain it, but it does have the triple knocking followed by a welcome by the [Dean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_of_Canterbury) (which also occurred slightly later in the Welby ceremony).

Is there a precedent for this question-and-answer text in Anglican or earlier practice? (I don't mean just the scriptural allusions, but the use of a question-and-answer format when welcoming a new bishop.) What is the rationale for having the interview with a member of the laity?

Comment: This text seems to have followed Justin Welby from the Diocese of Durham: http://www.durham.anglican.org/news-and-events/news-article.aspx?id=214

Comment: It is similar to the questioning of the bishop after he has questioned his clergy during the Renewal of Ministerial Commitment at the Chrism Mass on Maundy Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to try to address the second question, "What is the rationale for having the interview with a member of the laity?"

It does not seem clear from the ancient Canons that laypeople were explicitly called to approve and/or examine a candidate bishop.  It seems, though, that a bishop's election had to be approved by laypeople as well as clergy by the time of the 5th century, at least in some jurisdictions.  Leo the Great wrote:

> When therefore the choice of the chief priest is taken in hand, let
>   him be preferred before all whom the unanimous consent of clergy and
>   people demands, but if the votes chance to be divided between two
>   persons, the judgment of the metropolitan should prefer him who is
>   supported by the preponderance of votes and merits: only let no one be
>   ordained against the express wishes of the place: lest a city should
>   either despise or hate a bishop whom they did not choose, and
>   lamentably fall away from religion because they have not been allowed
>   to have when they wished.
>
> [Letter XIV, *To Anastasius, Bishop of Thessalonica*](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf212.ii.iv.xiv.html), Chapter VI,
>   "The Election of a Bishop must proceed by the wishes of the clergy and
>   people."

There is perhaps a still better answer, but since the question has remained unanswered for two years, I thought I would at least contribute this.